# How to repair "textured" ceiling texture

Tags: repair, painting, ceiling

I am in the process of making small improvements around the house prior to our starting to rent it out.  A few months ago a bit of the paint on a small part of the ceiling in our master bedroom fell off.  Originally due to the coloration (slightly yellow) around where the paint fell, I was worried about water damage.  I didn't feel any moisture, so wrote that off (hopefully justifiably).

Close up:
[image: Close up]

Full texture:
[image: Pulled out a bit to show full texture]

Either way, the paint falling off has not progressed any further, but I'd like to repair the damage, but am unsure how to proceed.  The room where the paint fell is the master bedroom, and as such, the largest room in the house.  Additionally, ***all*** of the rooms in the house have the same texture so I would really prefer not to remove the texture completely.

Does anyone have any idea how to reproduce this texture?  It seems like it was just a shift in the drywall, as it seems like there's a seam right where the paint fell.  I don't know the first thing about doing a textured ceiling, so help is very appreciated.

EDIT:

roofing issue that was causing the leak has been corrected - still unsure how to repair the "texture" on the ceiling.  It looks different than the popcorn texture, but not sure how to go about recreating it.

Comment: Bad news: that *does* look like water damage to me. Get that figured out first. Then you need to re-tape that seam and try to reproduce that texture. (Or get a pro in for a quick fix.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate the master is on the top floor, so I would assume it could either be a small leak in the sprinkler system, or maybe an issue with the roof (any other possibilities?).  I haven't noticed any progression of the issue, so I would guess the most likely culprit would be the roof, maybe only heavy rains/snow would cause further damage?  What kind of pro would you recommend contacting about assessing and correcting?

Comment: If you have access to the space above, take a look yourself. One thing to remember is that water damage isn't necessarily right where a leak is... water can travel before it makes its presence known. If you can't get in there, start with an inspection from a roofer. After that, it would be a pressure test on the sprinkler (though that might be up to a 3rd party like an HOA).

Comment: I don't know if commenting will bump my question, I was hoping for further response since I did the edit.  :O

Comment: Happy to hear that you got the leak fixed. Repairing the tape is straightforward enough, but the texture is puzzling. The only thing I can think of is that someone put a round blob of texture on their drywall hawk and pressed it up against the ceiling. If I'm correct, then the challenge will be to figure out the size of that blob. If you didn't want to do the work, any small drywall contractor could fix it.

Comment: We have the same exact ceiling throughout our HOME, AS DO ALL THE HOMES IN THIS AREA. I Was wondering if you found the correct tool for making this pattern?? Thanks!

Comment: I found this info from BournetexturedCelings.com-

The Standard Stomp texture, (also called the “Slapbrush” “Crows Feet” “Mopped”, “Chicken Scratch” and “Panda Paw”) was the industry standard for decades up until the late 1980s when knockdown textures took over.  Standard stomp is found in nearly every home built from the 1950s to the 1980s.
Want to hide flaws in your ceiling?Standard Stomp is your best bet.
Apply it with a consistent thickness to create a professional look to a texture that is largely shunned in modern times.